# Duplicate and alter text in a Word document using VBA Scripts

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to alter a Word document by using a Word VBA script. The Word document consists of bibliographic records. I would like to duplicate the first occurrence of field \TRF of each record and to change its field label (into \OTT). I recorded a VBA Script and it works fine if I position the cursor in front of the first occurrence of \TRF. I would like the VBA Script to repeat the alterations in the entire document but to only alter all first occurrences of \TRF. Recording a VBA Script with keyboard keys (Ctrl+F) plus text didn’t work. And my attempts to add vba code to the VBA Script where not successful.. What is the correct syntax I have to add to my VBA Script?

*Original text*:
(this example displays one record, the document contains more records)

\PPN 375496173
\TTT Pour un autre regard sur l'art beti / Bienvenu Cyrille Bela
**\TRF Cameroon**
\TRF Beti
\TRF sculpture
\TRF visual arts
\DAT 15-08-14
\DAV 20140815
\SIG AFRIKA 47231
\ISP text
\END

*Text after alteration*

\PPN 375496173
\TTT Pour un autre regard sur l'art beti / Bienvenu Cyrille Bela
**\TRF Cameroon

\OTT Cameroon**
\TRF Beti
\TRF sculpture
\TRF visual arts
\DAT 15-08-14
\DAV 20140815
\SIG AFRIKA 47231
\ISP text
\END

*Incorrect macro:*

```
Sub MacroCountry()  

' MacroCountry Macro  

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find  

'Search for \PPN (beginning of the record) and then search for \TRF  

      .Text = "\PPN"  
      .Text = "\TRF"  

'the selection part of the Macro works fine, it selects the line, duplicates it and changes the field label  

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.TypeText Text:="\Ott "

   End With 

  Loop  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find out a little bit more about MS Word framework so I used this as exercise. You could try this. Precondition is that all lines are ending with newlines so each line is a paragraph.

```
Sub InsertLines()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim line As String

    Dim inBlock As Boolean, found As Boolean

    Set doc = ThisDocument

    i = 1

    While i < ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        line = doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
        If InStr(line, "\PPN") > 0 Then
            inBlock = True
            found = False
        End If
        If InStr(line, "\END") > 0 Then
            inBlock = False
        End If
        If inBlock And Not found Then
            If InStr(line, "\TRF") > 0 Then
                doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.InsertAfter "\OTT " & Mid(line, 5)
                found = True
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions but I hope this is a solution at all. I tried a little bit with RegExp and Find object but this is more straightforward.